# On iPhone 12, how can I have Gmail emails read aloud like text messages?

Tags: gmail, accessibility, voiceover

I have an iPhone with the latest iOS.  If I give Siri the command "Read Text Messages", Siri will start reading the unread texet messages, from most recent to oldest.  Is there a similar voice command to have unread Gmail Primary Inbox emails read?  I have the Gmail app installed but so far the only way I have figured out how to read emails is to navigate to each individual one and execute the two-finger down gesture.

Comment: Google made the app, have you asked them?  If they didn't code it to accept and respond to siri commands outside of their app, nothing will work.

Comment: You can use both mail and Gmail simultaneously (Siri reads emails from Mail). You can also seek other clients that have such voice features built in, such as Outlook for iOS. Further, Google Gemini will provide a voice interface for consuming and producing email within Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

If the Gmail app doesn’t support Siri commands, you can add the account to Apple’s Mail app and have Siri read the unread emails.